# Axiomatic Quantum Theory, and the complex numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, probability, foundations

In Lucien Hardy's influential paper ["Quantum Theory from five reasonable axioms,"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101012) Hardy states in the abstract:

> This work provides some insight into the reasons why quantum theory is
>   the way it is. For example, it explains the need for complex numbers
>   and where the trace for- mula comes from.

Can someone explain to me why his axioms explain "the need for complex numbers" ?

Comment: It does not. You can always get away with complex numbers by using the standard 2D real plane. Complex numbers simplify the formalism in many cases though.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny: could you expand a bit on that comment ? Isn't he claiming that his axioms imply the complex numbers as an underlying algebraic structure ?

Comment: Do you mind giving part of the argument, as you understand it?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I honestly do not see a clear argument in his paper which implies that the complex numbers "follow" from his axioms.

Comment: I agree that I cannot see a clear argument in the paper which implies that the complex numbers "follow". To me, it looks like Hardy says: "in the case $N=2$, $K=4$, things look a bit like the Bloch sphere, so we successfully recovered quantum mechanics".
In https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S135521981500091X you can find an exposition of Hardy's paper, where complex number "appear" when looking at spin.