# To what extent does Hardy recover quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, foundations

In [his 2001 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101012), Hardy claims to recover quantum mechanics from five reasonable axioms. I am a mathematician and honestly admit that I don't understand the paper.

**I would like to understand exactly what is the formal statement that is claimed and proved in the paper. Can you give me a formal statement that looks like "recovering quantum mechanics" and is proved in the paper?**

Translating the paper into math, the set-up is the following: we consider two sets, $\mathfrak{S}$ (a set of states, assumed to have an extra convex structure encoding probabilistic mixtures) and $\mathfrak{M}$ (a set of yes/no measurements), and we consider a map $\mathbb{P} : \mathfrak{S} \times \mathfrak{M} \rightarrow [0,1]$, to be thought as the map encoding probabilites.

To my understanding, a statement like "we recover quantum mechanics" should (because I can't think of anything else!) be of the following form: there exists a (finite-dimensional) Hilbert space $H$, a subset $\mathcal{S}$ of the set of trace $1$ positive operators on $H$, a subset $\mathcal{M}$ of subspaces of $H$, a map $s : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathfrak{S}$, a map $m : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathfrak{M}$, such that for every $(S,M) \in \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{M}$, $\mathbb{P}(s(S),m(M)) = Tr(SM)$. However, the paper is far from proving such a statement!

Related (unnanswered) question: [Axiomatic Quantum Theory, and the complex numbers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500146/axiomatic-quantum-theory-and-the-complex-numbers)

Comment: I don't know about the discussion in the paper, but regarding your comment on how you formulate "recovering QM": why a finite-dimensional Hilbert space? If you already consider the problem of a spinless particle in $d$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^d$ you will work with $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d;d^dx)$, where $d^dx$ is the standard Lebesgue measure, which is already infinite-dimensional. If one wants to "recover QM" I see no way in which finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are enough.

Comment: It’s just because analytical subtleties do not appear in finite dimension. The problem is not about recovering examples of quantum models like the one you quote; it’s proving that you cannot do anything but think as states as rays in a Hilbert space, observables as self-adjoint operators, maybe derive Born’s rule, etc.